# Does xcode 4.2 Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 fully compatible with c++ exception?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

Does xcode 4.2 Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 fully compatible with/support c++ exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. LLVM/Clang supports C++ completely since LLVM/Clang 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Sure seems to be to me.

[Here is the Exception Handling in LLVM document for you to look at](http://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html).